# how many solutions does a 3x3 linear systems have?

Tags: linear-algebra

I just want to know if 3x3 linear systems has no solution, one solution, or two solutions, three solutions or infinitely many.solutions

Comment: There is no way to answer this without being given the actual system... Several of the options are possible (as seen in the answer by @5xum).

Answer (score 9):

It can have zero, one or infinitely many solutions.

***Examples:***

Zero solutions:

$$x+y+z=0\\
x+y+z=1\\
x+y+z=2$$

One solution:

$$x+0y+0z=1\\0x+y+0z=1\\0x+0y+z=1$$

Infinitely many solutions:

$$x+y+z=1\\x+y+z=1\\x+y+z=1$$